# window.addEventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I was trying to do like press enter key to trigger a function, but it does not work fine.Hope someone can tell me what is wrong. Here is the code:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", function () {
    if(key === 13)
        alert("Hello world");
});
```

Comment: `key` is undefined. What did you expect it to be?

Comment: Maybe you wanted the `.key` property of the event object that is passed as argument to your handler, but you'll need to declare a parameter for that.

Comment: You need to "debug" your code. The first step is opening the console. See if you notice any console errors. You will probably see something like "Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined". That will give you a clue as to what is wrong. Or, learn how to use "breakpoints" and place a breakpoint on the `if (key === 13)` line. When it stops there, examine the `key` variable and you will find that it is not defined. For more information on debugging, see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the event from the function that was attached to the keypress

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
            if(keyCode === 13)
                alert("Hello world");
        });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SZ9TG/1/